# Unable to access Java classes generated through JSON Files for development

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

While doing development at an old project, I am stuck at a weird situation.

In existing code, some of the Java Classes Schema are built through JSON files in the project.

Upon doing a `mvn clean install` I am able to see these generated classes(as POJOs) at the `target` folder.

But I am unable to use these classes for regular development (unable to access these classes at code)

**How do I access such Java generated classes at code ?**

I am using IntelliJ IDE.

Class Generation
[image]

Class unavailable for development

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the IDE to dicover generated source classes, the `target/java-gen` directory must be marked as **generated source** type. Usually IDE can discover the generated sources directory automatically, based on the corresponding Maven plugin configuration. When plugin do you use for generation?

You can try:

- using different options for the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | **Generated sources folders:** in [settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-importing.html);
- mark the directory as **generated sources** manually and make sure the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | **Keep source and test folders on project reload** option is enabled. Though you will probably need to mark this directory every time after the `target` directory is deleted (e.g. after the full rebuild).